# Simulation binaries file location

Tags: gatling

I am a first time gatling user. Trying to run the load test from a runnable jar file, jar file also happens to include the simulation binaries.

Considering above, what would be the argument value for `-bf`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The command line argument `bf` specifies the `request-bodies-folder` (a path to a folder):

> `-bf <path>` | `–request-bodies-folder <path>` | Uses `<path>` as the folder where request bodies are stored
>   *(http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/general/configuration.html#command-line-options)*

This folder contains files with data called [HTTP Request Bodies](http://gatling.io/docs/2.1.7/http/http_request.html#request-body) (e.g. JSON-files) you can use in a request, when running your load test.

> Note: When you pass a path, Gatling searches first for an absolute path in the classpath and then in the request-bodies directory.

Comment: Hey, Sorry for the late response. This works for me.